# How to Create a Sharepoint 2010 List for Company Time Sheet Tracking System?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, sharepoint-2010

dayHi,

We need to create a Sharepoint 2010 Site to track employee time sheet. The employee enters time sheet online each day, but he/she is not allowed to modify previous days' entries.

There will be a Client page (asp.net, Silverlight, whatever) serves as time entry page, which has two buttons: one for Sign-in one for Sign-out. When the buttons were hit, the backend Sharepoint 2010 list will be updated, but the user is not allowed to modify the list directly (only Office Manager can do so).

How to config this list for this purpose?

Please help,

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You could deny employees access to list and use a web part for the data entry (sign in/out) functionality. The web part can use elevated priviledges toget around the permissions issue that the employees would have.